# Azure Log Analytics - expanding a property

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I'm fairly new to using log analytics and not very familiar with the KQL language yet for queries.

I'm trying to do a query that will get the objectID value out of what appears to be a multi-valued property from the query. When I do a standard search to list the results in a table one of the columns is Properties, and the objectID is within that property column.

Not sure how to go about doing this so the results just show the objectID.

[image]

Comment: please try to add `project Properties.ObjectId` in your query, and see if the `ObjectId` can be shown. And also you'd better add your query in your question.

Answer (score 2):

It would have helped to see your initial kusto query included in the question.

Nevertheless, you can use the [project operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/projectoperator) of KQL to extract the `ObjectId` as:

```
T
| ..<the rest of your query>..
| project Properties.ObjectId
```

where T is the table you are trying to query.

Here are some resources for you to get started with Kusto Query Language:

- [Getting started with Kusto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/)
- [Write queries for Azure Data Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/write-queries)
- [Kusto Query Language (KQL) from Scratch](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/kusto-query-language-kql-from-scratch)